# Reflecting an object off of a wall once it has hit the wall

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

so I've been struggling with this for literally all of last week. To start I am currently working on an Unity project and here is the code I'm stuck on:

```
private RaycastHit hit;
private Ray cast;

private bool casthit;

void Start() {

    casthit = false;
    Ray cast = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);

}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){

    if (other.tag == "Enemy") {

        other.GetComponent<BasicEnemy>().setHealthLower(damage);

    }

    if (other.tag != "Turret" && other.tag != "Bullet") {

        //here is where we want to reflect this object

    }


}

void Update () {

    Ray cast = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);

    Physics.Raycast (cast, out hit);

    transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;

}
```

Basically what is happening is I have a turret that shoots bullets, when one of these bullets hit a wall I want it to be reflected off of the wall (or bounced off of the wall if you prefer the term). The reflecting off of the wall should work the same way as light would reflect off of a surface. Now the problem mainly being that I have no idea how these things work, especially because I basically need to somehow calculate an angle for the bullet to go towards (so just an y value I could give to the transform so that it will then continue to travel to the next direction.

As you can see I do already have some foundation in the form of raycasts and a hit ray (because I believe we will need the hit ray its normal at one point).

Sadly however I just simply do not understand where to begin with my calculations or even what sort of calculations I need to do. The usual `Vector3.reflect` hasn't worked up until now (or at least not in any of my previous calculations) and by now I have a hit a road block where I can't think of new things to try, so I very much hope one of you guys knows how to somehow manage to do this.

Thanks already!

Comment: You can go old school and read a book/articles on basic 3d vector math... (Not really good suggestion for SO)...

Comment: `Vector3.Reflect`. You give it an incoming vector and the normal of the surface it's reflecting off of, and it gives you the resulting vector. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Reflect.html

Comment: @SirBraneDamuj I habe tried Vector3.Reflect However I don't seem to be able to get the incoming vector right. I take it it should be the transform.position, however the thing is I am not trying to reflect the position, in truth I am trying to reflect the rotation, so Vector3.reflect using the transform.position doesn't work and transform.rotation is a Quaternion so that doesn't work either

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you don't use the built-in physics and re-invent your own solution?

Comment: @Tom Hey, sorry for the overly late answer, but yes there was at the time. The reason I couldn't use the normal Unity physics is because they are frame based, so if at one point the bullet object is on one side of the wall and the next moment he is at the other side because the bullet is going at a great speed this means the unity physics never execute. Unity physics are great for small things, but for this sort of stuff Unity physics are a bit shoddy

Comment: Check the Unity forums. You're not the only person having this problem, and there are several different solutions using the built-in physics engine.

Comment: @Tom oh well, that's cool :P but by now I have already long figured it out, but I might take a look at that stuff one day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found an answer to my own problem (at last).

For anyone interested here is the new code:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){

    if (other.tag == "Enemy") {

        other.GetComponent<BasicEnemy>().setHealthLower(damage);

    }

    if (other.tag != "Turret" && other.tag != "Bullet") {

        Vector3 reflectposition = -2 * (Vector3.Dot(transform.position, hit.normal) * hit.normal - transform.position);
        reflectposition.y = this.transform.position.y;
        this.transform.LookAt(reflectposition);


    }


}

void Update () {

    Ray cast = new Ray(transform.position, transform.forward);

    Physics.Raycast (cast, out hit);

    transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;

}
```